# Regex for matching everything except multi digit numbers

Tags: regex

Can some one provide me with a regex to match everything in a string except a multi digit number?

Example string: `a hello 656554   ho5w are you`

In the above example the number everything except `656554` should be matched. The digit `5` in `how` also should be matched.

I tried this: `((?![0-9]{2,}).)` But this matched the `4` in `656554` also.

Edit: Here's what I tried. https://regex101.com/r/Jm2GTW/1

Edit 2: Please go through the link above once.

Comment: `5` in `ho5w` isn't a multi-digit number. Please define better your expected result

Comment: You probably want to delete multi-digit numbers in a string (i.e. replace them with nothing). What you wrote is not possible with regex.

Comment: @GalAbra sorry. my mistake. i meant should be matched. update now.

Comment: @virolino i was trying to do with regex alone. is it really not possible?

Comment: When you say "everything", what do you mean? Do you want to strip out the numbers and return the string without them or match each word? What sort of output do you want? Just to clarify, `"foo 1 bar 22 baz qu88x"`, we want to produce `"foo 1 bar  baz qu88x"`?

Comment: @ggorlen yes. I want to strip out the number `656554`

Comment: @kcsujeet: in the way you explained it, no. But as I said, you can delete what you do not need, and you get what you want.

Comment: @virolino i'm well aware of that route. but i was expecting someone would come up with a way to do it with regex and help me out.

Comment: @kcsujeet: you can go that route using regex. See my answer below

Comment: Depending on the regex flavor you use, either try [`(?:\D+|^)(?:\d\D+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/Jm2GTW/3) or this one which needs lookbehind support: [`(?:\D+|(?<!\d)\d(?!\d))+`](https://regex101.com/r/Jm2GTW/4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data you're actually using, this pattern appeared to work

```
(\D+\d?\D)
```

But the strings that have a single digit get broken apart.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jm2GTW/2)

Comment: looks like it does. but doesn't work with the string i tried. link in my question.

Comment: Maybe use `\D` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`? It kills everything which is not a letter or a single digit. Also, I am not sure that OP wants several matches.

Comment: @kcsujeet What's not working?  The regex demos that I provide show that it worked?

Comment: @Shar1er80 please check [here](https://regex101.com/r/i7NzmR/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\d{2,}
```

Replace with nothing (i.e. delete).

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/m84ZrG/3).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match each word separately (split by spaces), you can use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/s8DjxB/3):

```
\b\d\b|\b(?:[^\d\s]*?\d?[^\d\s])+\b
```

It matches one of two scenarios:

1. A single digit.
2. A word consists of no 2 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\D*(?<=\D|^)\d?(?=\D|$)\D*`

Explanation:

`\D*` - match zero or more non-digits

`(?<=\D|^)` - poisitve lookbehind: assert what preceds is non-digit or beginning of the strnig `^`

`\d?` - match zero ro one digit

`(?=\D|$)` - positive lookahead: assert what follows is a non-digit or end of the string `$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W6R5BC/1)